# How to get count results based on a dataset column values

Tags: r, count, multiple-columns

I have the following dataframe:

```
Group   User    Manager Client  Other data1 Other data2
AG  TRUE    TRUE        FALSE       a       b
AG  TRUE    TRUE        FALSE       c       d
JU  FALSE   FALSE       TRUE        d       e
JU  TRUE    TRUE        FALSE       f       g
```

And I want to use a result like this one:

```
USER    MANAGER CLIENT  COUNT-AG    COUNT-JU
TRUE    TRUE        FALSE   2       1
FALSE   FALSE       TRUE    0       1
```

I can get the results only for one group or the other using something like this:

```
f = filter(dataframe, Group == “AG”)    
  result <- group_by(f,User,Manager) %>%
    summarize(count=n())
```

But I cannot find a way to get the count of the two groups in the same result.
Any ideas?

Comment: There is a 1-liner if you use data.table. 
You'll have to provide the code that produced your data.frame in order for someone to give you this 1 line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `spread` from `tidyr` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format after including 'Group' also in the `group_by`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(User, Manager, Client, Group) %>%
   summarise(Count = n()) %>% 
   spread(Group, Count, fill=0)%>%
   rename(COUNT_AG=AG, COUNT_JU=JU) 
 #   User Manager Client  COUNT_AG COUNT_JU  
 #  (lgl)   (lgl)  (lgl)  (dbl)     (dbl)
 #1 FALSE   FALSE   TRUE     0       1
 #2  TRUE    TRUE  FALSE     2       1
```

---

If we are using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, and use `dcast` with `fun.aggregate` as `length`.

```
 library(data.table)
 dcast(setDT(df1), User+Manager+Client~Group, length)
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(Group = c("AG", "AG", "JU", "JU"), 
 User = c(TRUE, 
 TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), Manager = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
 TRUE), Client = c(FALSE, 
 FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), Other_data1 = c("a", "c", "d", 
 "f"), Other_data2 = c("b", 
 "d", "e", "g")), .Names = c("Group", "User", "Manager", 
 "Client", 
 "Other_data1", "Other_data2"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I also added convert to avoid type conversion spread(Group, Count, fill = 0, convert = TRUE). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, you have to use data.table. This is done in the first line (+ counting done by .N). The second line does what you asked for:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df1)[, .N,  by = .(User,Manager,Client,Group)]
dcast(dt, User+Manager+Client ~ Group, value.var = "N", fill = 0L)

    User Manager Client AG JU
1: FALSE   FALSE   TRUE  0  1
2:  TRUE    TRUE  FALSE  2  1
```